# Getting image files from github folder with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, github, directory, subdirectory

I'm newish to js/jquery and even newer to AJAX. I have a portfolio project where I'm trying to build a simple calendar (right now I'm just using fullcalendar) that is automatically populated with photos taken on each particular day. Originally it was doing this with the Instagram API but my review for public permissions was denied by Instagram and so to make my project work I had to hand-name every file with the correct date on it.

Both with Instagram and with my method I got it to work locally, but once I began using github it no longer works.

If I navigate to http://ME.github.io/img/ I get a 404.

If I navigate to http://ME.github.io/img/2015-12-31.jpg it loads the correct image.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ME.github.io/img/",
    success: function(data){
        $(data).find('a:contains(".jpg")').each(function (){
            // will loop through
            console.log("Found a file: " + $(this).attr("href"));
        });
    }
});
```

Is there anything I can do about this? I'm assuming this is a github-specific issue since I had it working locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-origin requests are restricted usually, aren't on GitHub, too?
Use browser JS console, or Fiddler, to determine it.
If restricted, you should "proxy" your request by your back-end.